# remote login failed on windows XP, but remote telnet successful on mac

Tags: tcp, telnet, oracle-11g

I recently set up an Oracle DB, started the listener on port 1561, and enabled TCP access. I then opened that port to all incoming connections. When I get on my Mac - I can use

```
 telnet remoteserver 1581
 Connected to remoteserver
 Escape character is '^]'.
```

However, whenever I get on the XP machine I'm using as the oracle client - when I use telnet to see if the port is open, it tells me it can't access it. Thus, I can't connect remotely through oracle. Is there something I'm missing with outgoing connections with WindowsXP?

PS (I self navigated from SO)

Comment: do you have windows firewall turned on, or some other firewall software running?

Comment: You can have firewalled outbound connections? And no I don't

Comment: You sure can. not a windows guy but I've read that if you're running a somewhat-current version of Windows (XPSP2+) and haven't turned the built-in firewall off, you are running an outbound firewall already.

Comment: The computer needed to be restarted for all the firewall rules to take place thanks for everyones help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you verify network connectivity with ping in cmd prompt?  Assuming you do have a network connection to your Oracle server, if the only difference is Windows / Mac, it's probably the Windows default firewall settings.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283673

Note These steps are only for Windows XP SP2 and Windows SP3. They are not for earlier versions of Windows XP. If you are not sure which version of Windows XP you are running, go to the "How to determine your current service pack" section.

To disable Windows Firewall, follow these steps:

```
Click Start, click Run, type Firewall.cpl, and then click OK.
On the General tab, click Off (not recommended).
Click OK.
```